# Execute two observables at the same time without converting them to promises

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous, observable

I want to call a number of API endpoints at once (asynchronously). I get an Observable from a single API call, and I want to "await" them all together, and get the results from each call to handle as a collection, preferably with an option to handle the exceptions (if any) from each one. Much like `asyncio.gather()` but for Angular. I don't want to convert the observables to promises, and I don't want to use deprecated methods such `forkJoin()` or the `async` pipe. Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`forkJoin` is actually not deprecated [but some overrides of it are](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/forkJoin.ts#L30).
An array of Observables or a dictionary are valid inputs to `forkJoin`.

This shouldn't throw any warnings about deprecation.

```js
const sources$: Observable<any>[] = [obs1$, obs2$, obs3$]
forkJoin(sources$).subscribe()
```

Answer (score 0):

So instead of 'converting' the observables to promises (I assume you're referring to `toPromise()`), you just wrap the subscriptions in promises. Then you use `Promise.all()` to await them concurrently.

```js
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  async waitForResponses() {
    const obs1 = this.http.get('api1');
    const obs2 = this.http.get('api2');
    const obs3 = this.http.get('api3');

    const promise1 = new Promise((resolve) =>
      obs1.subscribe((result) => resolve(result))
    );
    const promise2 = new Promise((resolve) =>
      obs2.subscribe((result) => resolve(result))
    );
    const promise3 = new Promise((resolve) =>
      obs3.subscribe((result) => resolve(result))
    );

    const [result1, result2, result3] = await Promise.all<any>([promise1, promise2, promise3]);
    
    console.log(result1);
    console.log(result2);
    console.log(result3);
  }
```

This awaits all api calls concurrently, but you could await them in any order you like.
`Promise.all()` returns an array of the results, at the same index as their respective promise. I'm pretty sure that's exactly what you're looking for.

Error handling:

```js
    const promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
      obs1.subscribe({
        next: (result) => resolve(result),
        error: (err) => reject(err),
      })
    ).catch((err) => console.log(err));
```